# how to get safari to autofill a credit card expiration date month/year select tag?

Tags: html, autocomplete, safari, credit-card, autofill

I have a form with select tags labeled autocomplete='cc-exp-month' and autocomplete='cc-exp-year'.  Chrome will autofill them fine but safari does not fill them.  Both chrome and safari fill in the input on the same form labeled autocomplete='cc-number'. Changing tag autocomplete tag to the more general 'cc-exp' didn't seem to help in Safari on either field.  Does anyone know how to get Safari to fill out the month and year of the expiration date?

Comment: Wow, please don't have `autocomplete='cc-number'` for a credit card number. Or any other card holder details for that matter.

Comment: Why not? I think it's a good feature and helps a lot to the users.

Comment: what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

For the element that you want to autocomplete, give it the attribute autocomplete="on".  Be cautious with this; it's convenient, but as Alex K. said, not a good idea.  Before you start dealing with peoples' information, please take the time to learn about security and at least the most common vulnerabilities.  Here's a page explaining the risks of autocomplete.

https://www.hackavoid.com/news/2-why-you-should-avoid-autocomplete-on-login-forms

and hackthissite.org is *awesome* if you're interested in learning how vulnerabilities are exploited.

Best O' luck, I hope this helped.